# regular expression for web crawler

Tags: java, regex

I was going thorough code snippet for web crawler written in java.It has used String url = "http://www.wikipedia.org/" to start the crawling and   regular expression "http://(\w+\.)*(\w+)".can anybody exaplain meaning of it?

Comment: Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. An additional link that may be of interest is [matching urls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496), which is listed under "Common Validation Tasks".

Answer (score -1):

Well, let's [look at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), shall we?

- The text `http://` will be matched literally.
- `(...)` denote capture groups
- `\w` means "a word character"
- `+` means "one or more of the previous thing"
- `\.` means a literal dot (`.`)
- `*` means zero or more of the previous thing (everything in the capture group)
- Then another capture group for word characters